# How to delete based on group select in PostgreSQL 14?

Tags: postgresql-14

How to delete based on group select?

```
Delete From syscount Where pid < (Select Max(pid) From syscount Group By count_type, iccid)
```

the purpose of the above delete query command is to delete all based on pid value that having the lower value than current max pid value of the group of count_type and iccid

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it seems you don't want to group by these columns, but instead to select based on these columns:

```
Delete From syscount s1
Where pid < (Select Max(pid)
             From syscount s2
             where s1.count_type == s2.count_type
               and s1.iccid = s2.iccid
            )
```